# Radius of Influence - groundwater pump well

Tags: groundwater

What is the best method for calculating radius of influence for a pump well in an unconfined aquifer?

I know the aquifer transmissivity (T), storativity (S), pump rate (Q), aquifer thickness (b), saturated thickness (h), and I have a rough idea of the aquifer recharge.

I have two thoughts for calculating ROI:

(1) I could use the Thiem-Dupuit Method and back calc for my radius (r2) at which the drawdown is 0. There is a nearby well being pumped at a similar rate and I am applying the drawdown at this well (r1) to my own well.

[image: Thiem-Dupuit]

(2) I could use an empirical method like one found [here](http://hatariwater.tumblr.com/post/138690184404/overview-of-the-radius-of-influence), but I noticed I get very different values for my ROI compared to what I calculate using Dupuit.

If you have any insight or experience in this matter, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!